# Docker with nginx shows only nginx start html

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I try to get more familiar with docker-compose and nginx but struggling with this problem.
I want to start a docker container with nginx and change the root volume in the nginx config.

So at first this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
```

And this is my site.conf:

```
server {
        index index.html;
        server_name php-docker.local;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        root /code;
    }
```

In my */code* directory is a simple Hello World HTML-file named *"index.html"*.

If I run `docker-compose up` and use the URL php-docker.local (I also added it to my /etc/hosts), I get only the "Welcome to nginx" Site and not my HTML-file.
I also checked the nginx.conf directly in the docker container, if this on is not loading my site.conf, but it will be included with `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

Does someone know what I did wrong? I also searched a lot, but only find examples like this.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I found my fault:
I need to run `php-docker.local:8080` in  my browser